# New column containing string that appears the most in the row

Tags: r, dplyr

Im trying to Create a column with the string that appears the most in the row and create another column with the number of times this most prevalent string appeared.

To facilitate my question this is what im trying to achieve:

My actual DF

[image]

What im trying to obtain:
most prevalente category and count

[image]

example df:
d

```
f <- data.frame(ID = 1:4,
           V1 = c("A","B","C","D"),
           V2 = c("A", "B","D","B"),
           V3 = c("A","C","D","B"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
count <- sapply(apply(f[, -1], 1, table), max)
count
# [1] 3 2 2 2
category <- names(sapply(apply(f[, -1], 1, table), which.max))
category
# [1] "A" "B" "D" "B"
f2 <- data.frame(f, category, count)
f2
#   ID V1 V2 V3 category count
# 1  1  A  A  A        A     3
# 2  2  B  B  C        B     2
# 3  3  C  D  D        D     2
# 4  4  D  B  B        B     2
```

Comment: I find your solution far more elegant, but for curiosity's sake, the data.table solution seems to be 60% faster testing with 1000 rows

Comment: The `data.table()` functions are optimized for speed. If you have a very large data set, that approach will save you time.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:4,
                V1 = c("A","B","C","D"),
                V2 = c("A", "B","D","B"),
                V3 = c("A","C","D","B"))


library(data.table)
setDT(df)
other <- melt(df, id.vars = "ID", measure.vars = c("V1", "V2", "V3"))
other <- other[, .N, by = .(ID, value)]
colnames(other) <- c("ID", "category", "count")
other <- other[, .SD[which.max(count)], by = .(ID)]

res <- merge(df, other, by = c("ID"))
res
```

Answer (score 1):

- We can use `dplyr` `rowwise` function to apply `table` to each row from `V1:V3`

```
library(dplyr)

df |> rowwise() |> 
      mutate(category = names(table(c_across(V1:V3)))[which.max(table(c_across(V1:V3)))] ,
      count = max(table(c_across(V1:V3))))
```

- Output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
# Rowwise: 
     ID V1    V2    V3    category count
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <int>
1     1 A     A     A     A            3
2     2 B     B     C     B            2
3     3 C     D     D     D            2
4     4 D     B     B     B            2
```